# Как с помощью php разбирать вложенный запрос

Tags: php, mysqli

Вот результат запроса:

```
страна 1 | игра 1 | игрок 1 команды 1 для игры 1 | игрок 1 команды 2 для игры 1
страна 1 | игра 1 | игрок 2 команды 1 для игры 1 | игрок 1 команды 2 для игры 1
страна 1 | игра 1 | игрок 3 команды 1 для игры 1 | игрок 1 команды 2 для игры 1

страна 1 | игра 2 | игрок 1 команды 1 для игры 1 | игрок 1 команды 2 для игры 1


страна 2 | игра 1 | игрок 1 команды 1 для игры 1 | игрок 1 команды 2 для игры 1
```

Как такой результат запроса разбирать с помощью php? Хоть небольшой пример пожалуйста...

Это результат вложенного запроса mysqli, а не строка.
Как циклом обработать данный результат запроса...

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "разбирать вложенный запрос"?

Comment: скажем составить дерево стран с играми и составов к этим играм. Как правильно обработать с помощью php такой результат запроса...

Answer (score 0):

Непосредственно код писать не буду, опишу лишь принцип. Описывать буду на упрощённом примере, в котором соединяются 2 таблицы, на большее количество таблиц делается аналогично. Предположим, у нас есть такой результат:

```
ключ | значение
a    | 1
a    | 2
b    | 3
b    | 4
b    | 5
c    | 6
```

Мы хотим получить

```
[
    a => [1, 2],
    b => [3, 4, 5],
    c => [6]
]
```

Для этого применяем следующий алгоритм:

1. Изначально результат - пустой ассоциативный массив (`[]`)
2. Выбираем следующую строку результата запроса (`a | 1`)
3. Если ключа нет в результате - добавляем в результат пустой массив по ключу (`[ a => [] ]`)
4. В массив, хранящийся по ключу добавляем значение (`[ a => [1] ]`)
5. Если в результатах запроса есть ещё строки - переходим к п. 2

Для того, чтобы этот алгоритм заработал на результате соединения большего количества таблиц, на шаге 3 нужно добавлять не просто массив, а ассоциативный массив, содержащий нужный ключ, по которому содержится другой ассоциативный массив и т. д. Выполнение шага 3 на ваших данных должно дать такую структуру:

```
[
    'страна 1' => [
        'игра 1' => []
    ]
]
```

Comment: то есть сначала нужно создать еще 1 массив, в этот новый массив расфасовать из массива, вернувшая бд данные и потом из этого массива с расфасованными данными выводить результаты на экран? Сразу вывести расфасовано я так понимаю не получится?